# Delphi, Win7, Form problem, Compatibility

Tags: delphi, forms, windows-7, compatibility

We have Win7/x64 with Delphi6. Many things are working like in WinXP, but I found a very disturbing phenomenon.

Many times on build I placed in the source, and try to use this function. Then Delphi starting to put all forms into foreground. When it finished with build, many forms I see, and I need to close them to back to source.

More disturbing that sometimes on build, or load project, or ???? the Delphi also start to push to forms into foreground place, but it hanged on this operation. Every form is touched and bringed to top window, and they are visible in the task tray too. When all visible, Delphi hide them all. And start again from the beginning.

I need to close process then.

I tried to set compatibility WinXp on Delphi, but then, when I try to open a dpr with ShellExec, or DblClick, I got system warn to "The process want to modify the system", and when I clicked on allow (Yes), the dpr not loaded... :-(

Do you have same problem?

How to solve it?

Thanks:
   dd

Comment: Is this a plain Delphi-6 or a Delphi-6 with loads of 3rd party stuff?

Comment: Delphi 6 with many 3rd pss... :-(

Answer (score 6):

Let me start that you cannot seriously expect a 2001 software development product like Delphi 6 to fully work with a 2009 operating system like Windows 7 that has since then undergone major structural changes.

Development products by nature work at the edge (usually cutting, sometimes turning into bleeding) of what is possible at the operating system versions that were current at their time.

Changes in operating systems sometimes cause software to stop working, or to limit their functionality. This is more so for development software.

In this case, major changes introduced since Windows Vista, like UAC, session management, video output and task bar management will affect your Delphi experience.

That is one of the reasons that Delphi 2007 got released with 2006 backward compatibility: to solve many of those problems.

That said, there are basically three options for you:

- run Delphi under a Windows XP virtual machine (in Windows 7, you can use [XP mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) for free if you have Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise or Ultimate, or something commercial like [VMware workstation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation)/[player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmware_player), [Virtual-PC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_pc), [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox)VirtualBox and others in Windows 7, or
- learn about UAC and other new features, and how they influence software in general, and more specifically software development environments; then install Delphi 6 working around parts of the limitations and live with the remaining limitations
- upgrade to a newer Delphi version: Delphi XE (unicode) works fine, and gets you a free Delphi 2007 (non-unicode) which works nicely as well

--jeroen

Comment: @Jeroen I'm running D6 happily on a 64 bit Win7 machine with UAC enabled. I don't run it as administrator. I did the same on Vista when it came out.

Comment: @David: you probably did my tip 2: learn about UAC and other new things.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes I like to think I've got a pretty good handle on the new features introduced in Vista! But it really doesn't take much to get D6 running fine with UAC. In fact I think the registry virtualization will actually make it a reasonable out of the box experience.

Comment: @Jeroen I'm also running D2010 which still doesn't fully understand UAC. I don't think the good people at Embarcadero have enough of a habit of running with UAC enabled.......

Comment: And how to use UAC? Do you have some short desc. about it? Thanks: dd

Comment: @durumdara Do you have any experience of UAC yet? If not then I suggest you do a websearch and look at the various articles on MSDN that explain it rather well.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your description, I'd say that you have a serious virus infection problem on your PC, but that's just me.

Comment: not necessarily, with Delphi 7 I'm experiencing "interesting" behavior in a clean virtual machine, I suspect the issue is related to the IDE being bloated with third party components which is not handled very well by the IDE... of course I can be wrong, there can be a million reasons for the issue he/she is experiencing.